# Is the package expo-firebase-recaptcha still working in 2024?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, recaptcha

I need to implement the function `signInWithPhoneNumber` provided by the **firebase SDK** in my *react native - expo application*.

This function, requires a recaptcha validator, but, the official Firebase documentation does not provide any information about official packages or workarounds we can do in order to use the recaptcha validation in react native.

On the other hand, the package `expo-firebase-recaptcha` is not working, whenever I use this component:

```
<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
     ref={recaptchaRef}
     firebaseConfig={_firebaseService.options}
     attemptInvisibleVerification={true}
 />
```

The app throws an error saying that the package `expo-firebase-recaptcha` does not find the `react-native-web-view` package in the `node-modules` folder, but, when I **install the `react-native-web-view` package** the app does not even start in my phone.

I am using the command `npx expo start` for starting the app in the `expo-go app`.

> [!NOTE]
> "If the app doesn't work with Expo Go, it's even less likely to work with `npx expo run:android`."

> [!NOTE]
> I am using the 50.0.11 version of expo sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library is no longer actively maintained.  Expo has written [a migration document](https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/firebase-migration-guide.md) for it to [React Native Firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/).

Comment: So, is the `react-native-firebase` package the only official alternative we have to do this in react-native with expo?

Comment: I wrote this article on the subject: https://www.buymeacoffee.com/gregfenton/expo-react-native-firebase